# GroupBy JPA y Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Qué tal, tengo un problema con una consulta en mi proyecto de Spring Boot usando JPA en mi clase repository tengo

```
List<Reporte> findByIdClienteFechaGreaterThanEqualAndTipoNotOrderByFechaGroupByFechaAndTipo(int cliente, Date fecha, int tipo);
```

Al llamarlo en mi clase control:

```
public String detalleReporte(int cliente, Date fecha) throws ParseException {
        String detalle = "";
        Reporte reporte = new Reporte(cliente, null, fecha, 0);
        List<Reporte> lista = reporteRepository.findByIdClienteAndArchivoAndFechaGreaterThanEqualAndTipoNotOrderByFechaGroupByFechaAndTipo(
                reporte.getIdCliente(), reporte.getArchivo(), reporte.getFecha(), reporte.getTipo());
        System.out.println("Registros encontrados " + lista.size());
        for (Reporte repo : lista) {
            detalle = repo.getFecha() + " | " + repo.getTipo();

            System.out.println(detalle);
        }
        return detalle;
    }
```

Me manda el error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.repository.ReporteRepository.findByIdClienteAndArchivoAndFechaGreaterThanEqualAndTipoNotOrderByFechaGroupByFechaAndTipo(int,java.lang.String,java.util.Date,int)! No property groupByFechaAndTipo found for type Date!
```

Esto es por el atributo GroupBy ya que no he encontrado la forma de ponerlo en el método ¿Alguién sabrá como agrupar de esta forma? ¡saludos!

Answer (score 1):

el GroupBy no se puede usar como nombre de método, la lista de los parametros soportados los puedes ver en https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html en la sección **Table 2.3. Supported keywords inside method names**

La solución sería usar la anotación @Query en la declaración del método para que puedas usar el group by, tal y como está mencionado en https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html en la sección **2.3.4 Using @Query**

algo así:

```
    @Query("select r from Reporte r where r.idCliente = ?1..... group by fecha, tipo")
    List<Reporte> findByIdCliente(Integer idCliente...)
```